# How does setTimeout function work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

Can anyone please explain how does setTimeout function work in javascript?
I'm attaching a `onclick` listener to some HTML element and the `onclick` function provides a call back function there. When I click the HTML element, it redirect to another page. My question here will be the following :

1. Will the call back function be executed after the click? I did some testing and looks like it get dropped in the middle of some where.
2. If I put the call back function using `setTimeout(function(){...}, 0)`, does that mean it will be putting on a background thread and always being fully executed?
3. Can someone please help explain the mechanism behind the setTimeout function?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: You seem to be saying that the problem is that the callback function is not triggering. setTimeout is not going to help solve that problem. Can you provide the definition of the clicked HTML element and the associated js code?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the MDN page for setTimeout.

[MDN setTimeout Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

It would really help to see some code implementation but generally a callback with a timeout delay of 0 would call the given callback instantly.

Comment: It is not "instantly". It is queued to be called when the current thread terminates and the queue is empty.